# Can I get a completely flush plaster-in switch or socket?

Tags: electrical

I've seen recessed downlights that fit in/on the ceiling prior to plastering, then after the ceiling is plastered the light has no visible bezel, just a recess in which the light sits. Search google images for 'trimless downlights' for examples.

Is there a system to achieve the same effect with switches and sockets? The alternative is flat-plate switches and sockets, which is not quite what I'm after.

If it makes a difference to the answer I'm in the UK.

Comment: -1 because this seems very close to a shopping question.

Comment: Seems like we should have some leeway for new, novel, hard to find and unusual.  I agrees its "shopping" if its a "dime-a-dozen" type item (something very common).

Answer (score 0):

I think you still need a metal/plastic backing plate, if only for access.  Would you expect to  see screws, or just a flush surface?  Would you expect to demolish the overcovering of plaster to service the device?

You could achieve this effect by trimming a flat plate to sit inside the normal box cutout.  Mudding the switch would require building a dam around the switch cutout, perhaps modeling clay or some such.

The ideal plate would be a reverse of a normal plate, which rounds off into the wall.  This reversed model would cup upwards slightly, to hold the plaster.

Still don't like not having access.  Couldn't you do a nice wallpaper cover.  I've seen those that hide switches and outlets very well.  As I recall, Europe has some heavy duty coverings that would mask the switches quite well.

These [paintable wallpapers](http://www.grahambrown.com/us/wallpaper-type/paintable-wallpaper) illustrate what I mean  [image]